# Headphone to line out

Tags: audio, audio-conversion

My laptop has a headphone out port.  My PA wants a line in input.  I've been looking for an adapter or a USB to line out.  I haven't really found what I think I'm looking for.  But then I don't know a lot about audio.  Any ideas on how to convert headphone out to line out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect the headphone out port to your PA's line in, there's no risk, just a possible sound distortion if the volume on your notebook is too high, or lose definition if the volume is too low. If you keep the volume to 75%, and regulate the output volume from your PA, you'll do just fine.